# How to count users ahead and behind of a particular user in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pre-register form. After signup I have to show the current registerar his current position. The current position is determined by counting rows ahead and behind of particular row.

For example, if the signup ID of Jack Smith is 42 I want to show how many user are ahead of him registered and behind him. If the total record is supposed to have 200 enteries.

I am wondering how I can achieve this in MYSQL and PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _I am wondering how I can achieve this in MYSQL and PHP._ What have you  tried so far achieving that goal?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(id) as total FROM users WHERE id < 42;` You should post a code, that is not working so we can help you, but we will not write whole code for you.

Comment: I am newbie in PHP.

Comment: debute thanks  i got what i have to do now.. Thanks brother!

Comment: @dragonball you are welcome, good luck with coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) the number of id lower than your current user's id and the number of id higher :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM my_table WHERE ID < 42;
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM my_table WHERE ID > 42;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @vincenth but how should I retrieved the current position of the registerar?

Comment: It's a bit hard answering your question since there is no code, but once you insert the user's data, you could get his ID by using lastInsertId (cf. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php), then perform the queries above.

Comment: I did the same. Thank you @vincenth :)

Comment: If I answered your question, could you accept the answer, so that other users stumbling on your question might know there is an answer.